# Have Thunderbird run twice (2nd instance)

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird

I would too have two instances of Thunderbird on the same computer.

- The first one that would be a new one starting from now, meaning I would'nt have a lot of history.
- The second one would be for archive purposes only, and I would go there if I need to find older emails

How is this possible in Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Comment: You could try organizing your mail into sub-folders instead. Easiest way.

Comment: ***Yes, it is possible.*** You can have several profiles, or just start new one. You could also use the **Local Folders**, and move all existing folders and emails to there.

Answer (score 4):

Try to create two profiles by running `thunderbird -p`.